# Iterating Ajax response and creating Dynamic table on some condition

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a dynamic table with ajax response.
And want to put condition on check box like if item.statuscheck =1 will print checked Box with name and if item.statuscheck =0 unchecked box will display with same name.
i am able to display name dynamically. But problem is coming with check box.
Here is the code i am trying with. Please help me on this issue.

```
  success(response)
{
    $.each(response,function(index,item){
        var status;
        if(index >=0 and index <= 4)
    {
        if(item.statusCheck = 1)
        {
            status = <input type ="checked" checked/>
        }
        else{
            status =  <input type="checked" />
        }   
        var content = '<td>'+ status + '</td>'
                 +<td>' + item.fieldName +'<td>';
            $("#tableId").appent(content)
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: If this issue is related to typing error please use comment section. Typo are not really answers

Answer (score 1):

("#tableId").append(content)

Change appent to append

Comment: Sorry it was typing mistake . it is append only

Answer (score 1):

compare operator is `==` not  `=` assign.Also careful `'`and `"`

```
 success(response)
{
    $.each(response,function(index,item){
        var status;
        if(0 >= index <= 4)
    {
        if(item.statusCheck == 1)
        {
            status = '<input type ="checkbox" checked/>';
        }
        else{
            status =  '<input type="checkbox" />';
        }   
        var content = '<td>'+ status + '</td>'
                 +'<td>' + item.fieldName +'<td>';
            $("#tableId").append(content);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = item.statusCheck == 1 ? '<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />'+item.fieldName+'</td>' : '<td><input type="checkbox" />'+item.fieldName+'</td>';
$("#tableId").append($(content));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not `type = "checked"` its `type = "checkbox"`

```
success(response)
{
    $.each(response,function(index,item){
        var status;
        if(index >=0 and index <= 4)
    {
        if(item.statusCheck = 1)
        {
            status = <input type ="checkbox" checked/>
        }
        else{
            status =  <input type="checkbox"/>
        }   
        var content = '<td>'+ status + '</td>'
                 +<td>' + item.fieldName +'<td>';
            $("#tableId").appent(content)
    }

  }
}
```